# Solving inequality with the sum of coefficients of cubic polynomials

Tags: inequality, polynomials

Given $Q(x)=\sum^{n}_{i=1} P_{i}(x)$, with $P_{i}$ being a cubic polynomial written as, $P_{i}(x)=x^{3}+a_{i}x^{2}+b_{i}x+c_{i}$ and assuming roots of $Q(x)$ all real, what is the maximum value of the real constant $T$ such that:

$(a_{1}^2+...+a_{n}^2)\geq T(b_{1}+...+b_{n})$

With $Q(x)$ having real roots, the determinant $\Delta$ must be $\geq 0$ and equal to:

$\Delta=(\sum^{n}_{i=1} a_{i})^2(\sum^{n}_{i=1} b_{i})^2-4n(\sum^{n}_{i=1} b_{i})^3-4(\sum^{n}_{i=1} a_{i})^3(\sum^{n}_{i=1} c_{i})-27n^{2}(\sum^{n}_{i=1} c_{i})^2+18n(\sum^{n}_{i=1} a_{i})(\sum^{n}_{i=1} b_{i})\sum^{n}_{i=1} c_{i}).$

If the above statement is a proper starting point, what kind of arrangement would lead to the inequality of interest? Any other starting point?

Comment: Will $\frac{a_{1}^{2} + \ldots + a_{n}^{2}}{b_{1}+\ldots+b_{n}}$ not do? (assuming $\sum b_{i}>0$)

Answer (score 1):

$$Q(x)=nx^3+\sum a_i x^2 + \sum b_i x + \sum c_i$$

$$Q'(x)= 3nx^2+ 2\sum a_i x + \sum b_i$$

With three real roots for $Q$, the quadratic $Q'$ needs a non-negative discriminant, so
$$\left(\sum a_i\right)^2 \geqslant 3n \sum b_i$$

Further as $n\sum a_i^2 \geqslant (\sum a_i)^2$, say using CS inequality and equality is possible when all $P_i$ are the same cubic of form $k(x-r)^3$, we must have $T_{max}=3$.

Comment: Would it be possible to obtain a solution without using calculus?.

Comment: @Newcontestant It seems to me in this case a non calculus solution is likely to be convoluted, like your attempt with the cubic discriminant. Should be possible though I suppose, doesn't occur to me immediately.